# All fonts on page are smaller due to Wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Wkhtmltopdf is shrinking all of the fonts from my HTML document, causing the entire document to appear smaller once converted to PDF.

**What I've Tried:**

--disable-smart-shrinking: This makes the fonts appear more normal, but cuts off the right side of the page.

I have tried adjusting the margins as well along with disabling smart shrinking, but it does not seem to bring back the cut off parts of the page.

Are there any other commands likely to make the fonts appear normal sized?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Any commands which are likely to make the fonts appear normal sized?

Comment: @user350813 Can you please post your code!

Comment: Please check my answer to another similar question :[How to generate PDF with the exact font size specified in html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59470066/1903124)